# how to convert from unicode to utf8 in python?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, xbmc

I'm working on my python script to extract the data from sqlite3 database for xbmc media application.

I can see that in my code it will extract the data using the unicode object where I will have the strings `(u'`, `u` and `L`.

I want to convert it back to normal strings from unicode object to utf8.

Here is the code:

```
programs = None
daysLimit = 14
start = datetime.datetime.now()
end = start + datetime.timedelta(days = daysLimit)
cur.execute('SELECT channel, title, start_date, stop_date FROM programs WHERE channel')
programs = cur.fetchall()

print(programs)
cur.close()
```

Here is the xbmc log:

```
03:49:03 T:3628  NOTICE: [(u'101 ABC FAMILY ', u'The Middle -  The Ditch',
20140520170000L, 20140520173000L), (u'101 ABC FAMILY ', u'The Goonies', 
20140520173000L, 20140520200000L), (u'101 ABC FAMILY ', u'Pirates of the Caribbean: On Stranger Tides', 
20140520200000L, 20140520230000L), (u'101 ABC FAMILY ', u'The 700 Club', 
20140520230000L, 20140521000000L), (u'101 ABC FAMILY ', u'The Fresh Prince of Bel-Air -  Day Damn One', 
20140521000000L, 20140521003000L), (u'101 ABC FAMILY ', u'The Fresh Prince of Bel-Air -  Lucky Charm', 
20140521003000L, 20140521010000L), (u'101 ABC FAMILY ', u'The Fresh Prince of Bel-Air -  The Ethnic Tip', 
20140521010000L, 20140521013000L), (u'101 ABC FAMILY ', u'The Fresh Prince of Bel-Air -  The Young and the Restless', 
20140521013000L, 20140521020000L), (u'101 ABC FAMILY ', u'Summer Sexy With T25!', 
20140521020000L, 20140521023000L), (u'101 ABC FAMILY ', u'Paid Programming', 
20140521023000L, 20140521030000L)
```

I want to ignore the strings `(u'`, `u` and `L` so I want to make it look like this:

```
'101 ABC FAMILY ', 'The Middle -  The Ditch', 20140520170000, 20140520173000, 
'101 ABC FAMILY ', 'The Goonies', 20140520173000, 20140520200000, 
'101 ABC FAMILY ', 'Pirates of the Caribbean: On Stranger Tides', 20140520200000, 20140520230000, 
'101 ABC FAMILY ', 'The 700 Club', 20140520230000, 20140521000000, 
'101 ABC FAMILY ', 'The Fresh Prince of Bel-Air -  Day Damn One', 20140521000000, 20140521003000,
and so on...
```

Can you please tell me how i can convert from unicode object to utf8 using python 2.6 version?

Comment: You mean 'byte strings encoded to UTF-8'. Unicode strings *are* normal strings, really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to display data, INSTEAD you are displaying **python representation** if this object.

So it contains meta-data like u, L, etc.
If you want to display data the way you want, you should write a code to deal with it.

For example:

```
for row in cur.fetchall():
    print u"'{row[0]}', '{row[1]}', '{row[2]}', '{row[3]}', '{row[4]}'".format(row=row)
```

So it will look like

```
'1', '2', '3', '4'
'1', '2', '3', '4'
'1', '2', '3', '4'
```

But... as I can see, you make structure look like CSV-file(comma-separated values), do you? So, maybe, you should read about csv python module?

Comment: thank you very much, i can see it is working right now. When I try to use `print row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3].format(row=row)`, I will get an error: AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'format'. Any idea?

Comment: You should use `u"'{row[0]}', '{row[1]}', '{row[2]}', '{row[3]}', '{row[4]}'".format(row=row)`

Comment: The logic is: you are using **string** pattern to **format** your data, so you should use a string object and call a `format` method on it.

Answer (score 2):

- The `L` postfixes signify long integers. They are the same thing as (short) integers really; there really is no need to convert these. It is only their `repr()` output that includes the `L`; print the value *directly* or write it to a file and the `L` postfix is not included.
- Unicode values can be encoded to UTF-8 with the `unicode.encode()` method:

  ```
  encoded = unicodestr.encode('utf8')
  ```

Your beef is with the list representation here; you logged all rows, and Python containers represent their contents by calling `repr()` on each value. These representations are great for debugging as their types are made obvious.

It depends on what you do with these values *next*. It is generally a good idea to use Unicode throughout your code, and only encode at the last moment (when writing to a file, or printing or sending over the network). A good many methods *handle this for you*. Printing will encode to your terminal codec automatically, for example. When adding to an XML file, most XML libraries handle Unicode for you. Etc.

Comment: thank you very much for this, so how i can use the `encoded = unicodestr.encode('utf8')` to work with my code?

Comment: @user3667173: Yes, you can encode Unicode values to a UTF-8 bytes like that. **Just make sure you don't have better options**, like not encoding manually.